# what payload does twilio send via webhook when you recieve mms on twilio number?

Tags: twilio, mms

Does anyone know what payload is received via webhook when someone sends mms to twilio number ?
If someone can give a sample data that is recieved, then I can code accordingly.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

For inbound messages, we send a form encoded set of parameters that you can find here:

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sms/twilio_request

Hope that helps.